# Rendering image dynamically is so hard in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After trying various ways for hours and checking every relatable link, I couldn't find any proper way to render image dynamically in React.

Here is what i am trying to do.

I have an array of objects in which each object has a attribute called name. I am using map function map to loop over this array and returning of array of img element like shown below.

`<img className="img-thumbnail" src={require('../../public/images/'+item.name+'.png')}/>`

where item.name is the name of image file I want to display, for which require is giving me error "cannot find module".
Moreover I need to implement some fallback option, where rather showing broken images incase image file does not exist, i want to display default image

Here are the things I have tried:

- using try and catch block over require and calling this function from img element

  ```
  setImage(data){
  try{
      return require( '../../public/images/'+data+'.png' ) //actual image
  }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      return require('../../public/images/fallback.png'); //fallback
  }
  ```

  `<img className="img-thumbnail" src={this.setImage(item)}/>`
- using import, inside same function above, got error import cannot be called from inside of function
- using react-image library. Turned out it does not support local images.

Any help ?

Comment: What about `src="/images/fallback.png"` ? This is more a webpack, or whichever bundler you are using, question than a react js question imho.

Comment: Are those images available inside the app (static and part of the bundle) or are those uri's dynamically fetched from a server?

Comment: @johnnypeter Images are inside the app but objects i am fetching from database. Problem comes after component mounts because after that require do not seem to work and shows cannot find module while images are still present in the directory

Comment: @happysharma if your urls are known at compile time, I've added an answer that could help you

Comment: You are rendering "dynamic" images statically. If your images are public then simply fetch them by URL with the corresponding JSX/HTML element, if your images are not public then you would have to asynchronously fetch the base64 data (and the mime type) which can be done with something like "redux-saga" (although that seems overcomplicated for what you are trying to achieve).

Answer (score 1):

Here a tricky way to handle this. Use react `state` to check if there's error.

If true, show fallback, otherwise, show actual image.

```
setImage = (data) => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = '../../public/images/'+data+'.png';
  this.setState({
    hasError: false
  })
  image.onerror = () => {
    this.setState({
      hasError: true
    })
  }
  return image.src;
}
// into render
this.state.hasError
? <img src="../../public/images/fallback.png" />
: <img className="img-thumbnail" src={this.setImage(item)}/>
```

**Update:** Example

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'fake.jpg';

image.onerror = () => {
  console.log('image doesn t exist');
}
```

Comment: How are you checking if image exist or not ? Because i not able to fetch image using require once the component mounts though image is still there in directory

Comment: if the image doesn't exist, it will enter into onerror.

Comment: function is showing image exist but when require it again shows cannot find module

Comment: You don't need to use require() anymore.

Comment: without it images won't load. Web addresses don't work in react like that, you either import it at the top or require in src.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you need required it could be done simply like this. You can import something like this. Import image like this

```
import fallback from '../../public/images/fallback.png';
```

and for dynamic image i would suggest either make some key value pair. For ex :

let data =  {
    image1 : `../../public/images/image1.png`,
    image2 : `../../public/images/image1.png`
    }
and import it normal

and something in render

it could be something like this.

```
render(){
  return(
   <img className="img-thumbnail" src={img?img[type]:fallback}/> //something its just refrence(where type is something which you want dynamically add image)
)
}
```

Comment: src does not take path straight away. You use require or first import. Mine former case, but i am not able to do that once the component mounts

Answer (score 0):

Requires are statically checked during compile time. The path of requires cannot be dynamic. Since you have static images in your bundle and the object maps to one of these you can follow a solution to something as follows

```
const images = {
  image1: require('local/path/to/image1'),
  image2: require('local/path/to/image2'),
  image3: require('local/path/to/image3'),
}

const defaultImage = require('local/path/to/defaultImage');

const Img = ({ name }) => {
  // here name is the name for the image you get from api.. 
  // This should match with the keys listed the iages object
  return <img src={images[name] ? images[name] : defaultImage}/>
}
```

Comment: It will work for static images but not when path can be formed only after object fetched.

Comment: @happysharma since all your images are static, bundled in your app, you can map the name to path upfront by the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Above all answers were helpful but unforutnaley none of the method worked for me. So again digging little deep I found that require was giving error "cannot find module" because after webpack bundles my code, require lost the context. Which means the given relative path was no longer valid.

What i needed to do was preserve context which I did by using require.context;

Here is the final code that worked.

```
//getting the context of image folder
  const imageFolderContext = require.context('realtive/path/to/image/folder')

 //function to check if image exist
   checkFile(data){
       try{
            let pathToImage = './path/to/image/relative/to/image/folder/context
            imageFolderContext(pathToImage)  //will check if Image exist
            return true                      //return true if exist
       }catch(err){return false}
  }

//rendering image element dynamically based on item name and if exist or not
<img src={this.checkFile(itemName)?imageFolderContext('path/to/image/relative/to/context'):imageFolderContext('default/image/path/) />
```

don't forget to bind checkFile function